# funny error with my database

Tags: android

my app is contacts book , finally everything's working fine but when I, "the user", add new contact I get force close .. but the app didn't close, but rather just restarted ! and when i check the contact list i see that what i tried to add is really been added !!!
 logcat say the error is here :

```
return cursorToContact(cursor);
```

it is part of this add function:

```
    /** Add new Contact to Database. */
public Contact createContact(Contact contact) {
    //Used to store data like : COLUMN_NAME , VALUE.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, contact.getFirstName());
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, contact.getLastName());
    //Insert new contact and get the id of it.
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_FTS, null,
            values);
    //To show how to query (To get contact by it id).
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_FTS,
            allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, 
                             null,
            null, null, null);
    //Move Cursor to the first row.
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursorToContact(cursor);
}
```

so why is that happen > plz help me 
 note that i'm useing sqlite fts3 database

the cursorToContact :

```
    /** Used to get Contact data from Cursor to Memo Object. */
private Contact cursorToContact(Cursor cursor) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
    contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(2));
    return contact;
}
```

Comment: post the error with the trackback otherwise is not possible to know what is the cause

Comment: The `Contact` class where is defined?

Comment: @H4F - I edited it because it was hard to understand. Please at least capitalize i's - " I tried this and I want XYZ" , not "i tried ths and i want xyz" . But it's a good question.

Comment: @Adel >>bad english ,i didn't notes that thanks alot

Comment: @gipi sory what u mean? the error first line is :android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line actually adds the data to your database:

```
   long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_FTS, null,
            values);
```

Anything that happens after that is incidental (mostly).

If your query is messed up, your other parts will fail.  Your query:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_FTS,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, 
                         null,
        null, null, null);
```

looks appropriate.   The allColumns could be messed up, though.

Also, I'm not sure why you go to all the trouble of setting up a new contact in CursorToContact, only to return some other value.

```
    /** Used to get Contact data from Cursor to Memo Object. */
private Contact cursorToContact(Cursor cursor) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
    contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(2));
    return contact;
}
```

You never use contact.  I would have expected for you to return it.

Comment: thanks for god i finally solve it by detect the end of the data set in a different way which is :   cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contact = cursorToCONTACT(cursor);
   
   //Move Cursor to the next row.
   cursor.moveToNext();
  }
  // Make sure to close the cursor
  cursor.close();
  return contact;

Comment: @H4F - I think HalR deliberately left `return memo;` in the code to illustrate the problem. The description above it makes a little less sense when the invalid syntax is removed.

Comment: I did, indeed.  but it does make me feel better to see it changed by H4F.

Comment: @Leigh return memo; it was a " write error " so i fix it in my ques and HaIR answer

Comment: @HaIR would you please look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021996/inquire-about-a-database-query#) and thanks .

Comment: @H4F - Ah, okay. (Good call to change it in *both* places.)